# angularjs, how $scope parameter works behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Controllers take as a second parameter an anonymous function.

I have two examples of controllers, one with the anonymous function taking as parameter *nothing*, and the second taking the `$scope` object.

How angularjs "behind the scenes" can detect that my anonymous function has an argument or not? And how can I mimic that in a custom js method?

```
controller('ctrl',function(){
        console.log( arguments[0] ); // ->> undefined
    });
```

vs

```
controller('ctrl',function($scope){
        console.log( arguments[0] ); // ->> js object
    });
```

A pseudo code that I`m thinking is like this:

```
( if F has parameters ) F.bind($scope) // or F.call(....)
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking. If no arguments provided why would you expect `arguments[0]` to be defined?

Comment: It is how angular's Dependency Injection works, take a look at this code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L72

Comment: @charlietfl don't tell me that $scope is a global variable outside of the angular object, don' ya?

Comment: The `arguments` keyword got nothing to do with AngularJS. It's part of JS "core", as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: @BarbuBarbu no it is a registered `provider` within angular. There are numerous built in providers such as `$scope` and you can also create your own. You are injecting these registered providers as arguments

Comment: @charlietfl Correct for most injected values, `$scope` is a local though.

Comment: @devqon that is what I was looking for! Come and add it as a general comment, I`ll choose it as the fav one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is how angular's Dependency Injection works: it looks at the args names, then looks it up to know what to inject.

You can find the specific code for this here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L72

Answer (score 3):

As documented [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

> Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified
> Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created
> and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's
> constructor function as $scope.

So the first argument passed to the Controller's constructor function is the child scope instance $scope.
Since the `arguments` object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function, printing arguments[0] will print the first passed argument (i.e. $scope).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question is how does Angular know that it has to inject `$scope` (or anything for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Angular gets the names of the objects to inject from one of three places (only the first of these that exists is used):

- The `$inject` attribute of the function
- If instead of a function you give it an array then the function should be the last element of the array and the injectable names are all the others.
- Otherwise it inspects the arguments the function is actually expecting by calling `toString()` on the function and extracting the names from that.

Once it has a list of names the injector will find objects first in a mapping object that may be passed to the injector and then in the objects that have been registered in the available angular modules. Again the first matching object is used, so the code to invoke a controller passes a unique `$scope` object to the injector for each controller but most other names you can use such as for services are singletons and the same object is reused each time.

You can use the injector yourself:

```
var injector = angular.injector();
function MyFunction(something) { ... }
injector.invoke(MyFunction, this, { something: anObject });
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector